# Remove <br> in a specific div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to remove all `<br>` tags in the div class `category alternate` but for some reason I can't get it work.

Here is what I got so far:

```
$('div.category alternate').find('br').remove();
```

Comment: That should work, your selector is wrong. What's the HTML look like?

Comment: What do you think he means? You have some HTML being sent to the browser, and you want to modify the elements, right? Well, *"What does the HTML look like?"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="category alternate">
   whatever<br>
</div>
```

then you want this:

```
$('div.category.alternate br').remove();
```

On the other hand, if your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="category">
   <div class="alternate">
     whatever<br>
   </div>
</div>
```

then you want this:

```
$('div.category .alternate br').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an `<alternate>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

`$('div.category alternate')` tries to find all `alternate` tags inside  `div` with class `category`. Maybe you ment `$('div.category .alternate')`

Comment: the div class is "category alternate"

Comment: Use `div.category.alternate`. This is because a space in a class list means another class name, therefore it has two classes, `category` and `alternate`, not one class called `category alternate`

Comment: You don't need the tag name in the selector. Just use `.category.alternate`.